# Why am I getting overflow? (NASM Assembler)

Tags: assembly, nasm, integer-overflow, irvine32

I have to make a program that calculates the volume of a cone which is 22/21*(r^2)*h for purposes of this program.

So this code I developed works for me for any variables that don't cause the EDX register to become populated after multiplying the variables together. I can't shift registers or "OR" them together, nor can I use jumps or cmp statements. I also must use 8 bit registers for the height and width variables, 16 bit for the radius^2 and radius^2*height calculations, and then finish it off with 32 bit for the final division calculation. Take a look. I don't know why it is overflowing into EDX and I don't know how to correct it...

```
.data

radius          WORD ?                                      ;var for radius
height          WORD ?                                      ;var for height
numerator       WORD 22                                     ;Making a variable for numerator
denominator     DWORD 21                                    ;Making a variable for denominator
volume          DWORD ?                                     ;Making a variable to store volume main
decimal         DWORD ?                                     ;Making a variable to store volume remainder
prompt BYTE "Enter the radius: ",0                          ;val for radius prompt
promp2 BYTE "Enter the height: ",0                          ;val for height prompt
result BYTE "The volume of the cone is: ", 0                ;val for printing volume
decim  BYTE ".", 0                                          ;val for decimal place

                                                                ;volume of cone is 1/3(pi(r^2)h) or 22/21(r^2)h

.code

main PROC
    mov edx,OFFSET promp2                                       ;move prompt into edx for printing
    call WriteString                                            ;ask user for height

    mov eax,0
    mov edx,0
    mov ecx,0
    mov ebx,0                                                   ;move zero into all main registers

    call ReadDec                                                ;reading the height
    mov bl,al                                                   ;move height into storage

    mov edx,OFFSET prompt                                       ;move promp2 into edx for printing
    mov eax,0                                                   ;re-zero eax
    call WriteString                                            ;ask user for radius
    call ReadDec

    mul al                                                      ;obtain r^2
    mul bl                                                      ;multiply r^2 by height
    mov edx,0                                                   ;zero out edx
    mov dx,numerator                                            ;move numerator into dx
    mul dx                                                      ;multiply r^2*h by 22

    mov ebx,denominator                                         ;move 21 into ebx to divide
    div ebx                                                     ;divide by 21 to get total volume
    mov volume,eax                                              ;move volume into volume variable
    mov decimal,edx                                             ;move decimal remainder into decimal variable

    mov edx,OFFSET result                                       ;prepare string result for printing
    call WriteString                                            ;print result string
    mov eax,volume                                              ;move volume into eax to print     
    call WriteDec                                               ;print volume
    mov edx,OFFSET decim                                        ;move dec into print register
    call WriteString                                            ;print decimal
    mov eax,decimal                                             ;move decimal remainder into eax to print
    call WriteDec                                               ;print decimal value
    call CRLF                                                   ;carriage return and new line
    call WaitMsg                                                ;pause output

    exit
main ENDP
```

Maybe I could do different registers for the intermediate arithmetic, but I have no idea how to accomplish that given the current 8-8-16-16-32 requirements. If anyone could help me with a working solution and explain why it works, maybe step through it so I can understand why mine doesn't work for larger integers (most over 20 don't work) that would be amazing. Thank you ahead of time for any help you can give me!

Comment: If your problem is that `edx` is non-zero at the point where you do the division, then the solution would be to clear it: `mov edx, 0` (or `xor edx, edx`).

Comment: edx stores the 16 to 32bit overflow from multiplication as well as the remainder for division operations. I clear edx before moving "numerator" into it to perform the 16bit multiplication between AX and DX. For example, run this program and plug in 18 and 15 respectively. After multiplying AX and DX, EAX's first two bytes are filled and the remaining byte goes into DX which should be moved to the head of EAX by using shl EDX,16 and then or EAX,EDX, but I can't do that because it is a restriction on the program.

Comment: `div ebx` divides the 64-bit value in `edx:eax` by `ebx`. The result of your multiplication is in `dx:ax`. You either need to use variants of `mul` and `div` that operate on the same register pairs, or discard the multiplication overflow by clearing `edx` prior to the division.

Comment: But if I clear the multiplication overflow it gives an incorrect answer as the hex value for the correct answer will have changed. I thought switching from EBX to just BX would fix it, and it solved the overflow problem, but now it only divides what's in the AX register and not the combination of DX:AX.

Comment: So why don't you multiply by a 32-bit register (e.g. `mul edx`) so that the product ends up in `edx:eax`?

Comment: Okay, so I figured out the whole overflow thing, it's apparently normal activity, however, in order to do a div command on the upper and lower dx:ax registers I have to move the contents of dx into eax at the head, which I decided to throw into a shl edx,16 statement. However, now I don't get overflow with certain integers such as if I were to plug in 20 and 20 for the radius and the height. Would there be any reason why the overflow wouldn't store itself in dx like with smaller integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's walk through the whole calculation:

```
mul   al               ;obtain r^2
```

This `mul al` leaves a result in the `AX` register. So you must use a word multiply in the next line **or else you loose a part of the value of *r^2***.

```
mov   bh, 0
mul   bx               ;multiply r^2 by height
```

Now the result is in `DX:AX`. To multiply it by 22 you can move it to the 32 bit register `EAX` by means of the stack.

```
push  dx
push  ax
pop   eax
movzx edx, numerator   ;Why is this defined a word?
mul   edx
```

This time the result is in `EDX:EAX`, ready for the final division.

```
div   denominator
```

Finally move quotient in `EAX` and remainder in `EDX` to their respective variables.

```
mov   volume, eax      ;move volume into volume variable
mov   decimal, edx
```

Comment: ew, that's a horrible way to combine two 16bit values.  `shl edx, 16` / `or edx, eax`.  (Or if the upper half of eax contains garbage `shl edx, 16` / `mov dx, ax`.)  Or avoid the partial-register slowdowns that Intel CPUs pre-IvyBridge will have by simply using 32bit all the time.  `movzx  eax, al` and so on for other regs if necessary, then do stuff like `imul eax, ebx`, `imul eax, edx`.  If you don't want the high half of the result, `imul` with 2 or 3 operands is a better choice, because it's faster and you're not stuck with eax as a dest.